# Having trouble with generator in list comprehension

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, list-comprehension, generator-expression

I am trying to do one liner of one challenge in codefights , but I seem to be stuck with:

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

when I execute

```
def magicNumber(n):
    return [i for i in itertools.takewhile
                       (lambda x: x % d for d in [3,5,7] == 0, range(0,n))]
```

The challenge is:  *Consider the numbers the only prime factors of which are 3, 5 and 7. Write a program to find the nth largest among them.*

Example output :

- For `n = 1` the output should be: `1 (3^0 * 5^0 * 7^0)`.
- For `n = 2` the output should be: `3 (3^1 * 5^0 * 7^0)`.
- For `n = 6` the output should be: `15(3^1 * 5^1 * 7^0)`.

I know I am far from solving it with this I just want to know what's the problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the parenthesis:

```
takewhile(lambda x: (x % d for d in [3,5,7] == 0), range(0,n))
```

Note that your original code was parsed as:

```
takewhile((lambda x: x % d) for d in [3,5,7] == 0, range(0,n))
```

i.e. the parser thought you was creating a generator yielding `lambda`s as first argument to `takewhile`. And you are doing a function call to `takewhile` with two arguments, which requires parenthesis around the generator, so if you really wanted to do that you had to write:

```
takewhile(((lambda x: x % d) for d in [3,5,7] == 0), range(0,n))
```

Comment: This doesn't address the main problem, which is that the `== 0` was in the wrong place.

Comment: This solves syntax error which is the goal of my question , thanks. Also thanks for how the code will be parsed. I am not sure ` == 0 ` is at the wrong place I feel it more intuitive like that. EDIT : Nevermind I realized what you mean I fixed it.

Comment: @TomKarzes I disagree. The main problem is a **syntactical** error, not a semantic error. That would be a *follow up* question.

Comment: Well, there were a couple problems.  The parentheses fixed the grouping problem, but the `== 0` seemed like a bit more than that.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your generator expression in `lambda` function in a parenthesis, also I think you need to check the equality of the result of `x % d` with zero:

```
lambda x: (x % d==0 for d in [3,5,7])
```